# IF statement causing SET PATH to fail

Tags: batch-file

I'm writing a simple batch script on Windows 7 to add some some environmental file paths. Trouble is, my set path command is failing because of spaces in the existing path:

```
SET PATH=C:\oracle\ora92\bin;C:\Program Files\Oracle\jre\1.3.1\bin;%Path%
```

This fails with '\ Microsoft cannot be found' which refers I think to this in the existing %path% variable :-

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\
```

Is there a simple solution to this?

Update: 
Turns out the issue lies with a surrounding IF statement.This script throw up the mentioned error message:

```
IF "TEST" == "TEST" (
  ECHO Using TEST settings on %COMPUTERNAME%
  SET PATH="C:\oracle\ora92\bin;C:\Program Files\Oracle\jre\1.3.1\bin;%Path%"
  SET GDRIVE= (removed path)
)
```

But if I remove the IF statement, it works fine:

```
ECHO Using TEST settings on %COMPUTERNAME%
SET PATH="C:\oracle\ora92\bin;C:\Program Files\Oracle\jre\1.3.1\bin;%Path%"
SET GDRIVE= (removed path)
```

Does anyone know why an IF statement is causing the SET PATH to fail?

Comment: I had no problems doing the same on Windows 8.1 and I think I did the same already on Windows 7 ?!? Perhaps playing around with quotation marks will help: SET PATH="C:\Oracle\;...%PATH%

Comment: Remove the extra n in Bin. Paths don't need spaces quoted as they are delimited on semicolon not space.

Comment: It turns out the problem is with the surrounding IF block surrounding the SET Path statement. If I remove the IF statement, the batch runs fine.  I can't understand why though.

Comment: The real problem is not the space, but the fact that the IF block uses parenthesis, which cmd.exe sees as being closed by `Program Files (x86)`. rojo's answer gives the 2 solutions.

Answer (score 7):

To answer your question directly, the syntax for avoiding evaluation of parentheses and other special characters while setting a variable is `set "var=value"`.  But `set` is the wrong command to use here.  What you should do is

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
path C:\oracle\ora92\bin;C:\Program Files\Oracle\jre\1.3.1\bin;!PATH!
```

Delayed expansion will prevent your PATH variable's contents from being evaluated prematurely.  Type `path /?` from a cmd console for more information on the `path` command.

If you want your path additions to be persistent, see the `:append_path` function in the example script in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29439544/1683264).

Answer (score 0):

Using a `GOTO` command will allow you to move the PATH assignment outside of the `IF` statement.  This eliminates the issues caused by having the right parenthesis in the existing `PATH` variable.

```
IF NOT "TEST" == "TEST" (
    GOTO skiplabel
)

ECHO Using TEST settings on %COMPUTERNAME%
SET PATH="C:\oracle\ora92\bin;C:\Program Files\Oracle\jre\1.3.1\bin;%Path%"
SET GDRIVE= (removed path)

:skiplabel
ECHO Do other stuff as desired
```